# Are there any "advanced" use of hyperbolic functions?

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

There are a lot of uses of trigonometric functions. We have them in the Fourier series, and we frequently see them in physics. However, I have not seen any application of hyperbolic functions. Actually, I have only used them for nothing but the solution of second-order linear ODEs.

Could anyone tell me some advanced applications of hyperbolic functions?  For example, I know it can be used in Lorentz transform.

Comment: [Hyperbolic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry).

Comment: [9 year old thread talking about hyperbolic functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123/real-world-uses-of-hyperbolic-trigonometric-functions)

Comment: The trigonometric functions appear ubiquitously because they are the basic oscillating functions, and can be combined to model more complex vibrations. Also, they are related to complex numbers, which have diverse connections with everywhere else. The hyperbolic functions are the real analogue of the trig functions. They have applications, but not as varied as that if the trig functions.